# www prefix doesnt work on NOPCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce-3.90

I have developed a website through nopcommerce and everything works just fine, while testing I found that when I add www to my domain www.mydomain.com it doesnt work but when i hit mydomain.com it works just fine.

I found many replies for the same problem but none of them seem to have solved my problem, I also tried below
https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www

by using url rewrite it throws 500 error.

Please help

Comment: Do you have DNS record with www.mydomain.com pointing to your hosting server? Please use any DNS lookup tool e.g https://mxtoolbox.com/ to find out. Also what error you get when browsing with www.?

Comment: The page not found error comes.

Comment: Did you check your www. domain via mxtool dns lookup?
[https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx]https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx

Comment: I tried but it gave same result for both with and without www. But without www it works fine. May be I am doing something wrong my domain name is mgactivewear.com

Comment: So I found that your missing a CNAME record for your domain. For this login into your domain name provider panel and then add a DNS CNAME record with www pointing to A record. Check this [link](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/cname)

Comment: Is it possible if we can do something like whenever a request comes from www redirect it to non www one instead of adding cname in domain provider panel which is godaddy

Comment: I suggest add www cname dns entry

Comment: Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

After looking up the domain with www using MXToolbox it was found that no record was found. So suggested fix was to add www cname dns record for the domain by logging into domain provider panel.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having difficulties with versions older than 3.9. The problem for me was to specifically set the security url. You must leave it blank in the store configuration (or put without 3w to hack the logic) for nopcommerce to automatically detect it. Because before he checks whether or not 3w exists, he uses the url saved in this field, according to the method GetStoreHost:

```
if (useSsl)
{
    result = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentStore.SecureUrl)
    ?
    // Secure URL is specified. 
    // So a store owner doesn't want it to be detected automatically.
    // In this case let's use the specified secure URL
    currentStore.SecureUrl
    :
    // Secure URL is not specified.
    // So a store owner wants it to be detected automatically.
    result.Replace("http:/", "https:/");
}
```